# How to use c++ and python together and distribute them with systems not having python installed?

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I was working around combining c++ and python together and found that there is something called `<include Python.h>` which can be very helpful and calling functions from a python file or simply communicating with any python script.

I wondered how we will be able to distribute these binding i.e. a program of c++ communicating with a python script to systems not having Python installed or having unmatched versions of python installed.

Also I found that somehow Sublime Text packages Python runtime, libraries and python scripts to distribute to machines where python may or may not be installed. I wanted to know how is this done and what are the reference links which might be useful in knowing more on the topic.

[Sublime Text Root Directory Image containing distributable python runtime and python scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/533e0.png)

Similar kind of implementation was also seen with Google Backup and Sync Software.

Comment: you might be able to archive a python preinstallation into your app, have it unarchived when you install/run your app, then its just a matter of making your app recognize this python preinstall, this might not be easy if you want to support all platforms

Comment: @orenrevenge thank you very much for replying to the problem and infact I was also searching for a similar solution it would be great if you could help me with from where to get this python preinstallation pacakge and how to make my app recognize the python preinstallation. I know there is a method Py_Intialize in C++ but how can I pass in my custom python package or should i set the pythonpath environment variable at that time. Also how can I distribute the libraries used in scripts along with the python preinstall package

Comment: @orenrevenge I researched on this and found two links which might be helpful, can you please look after them and tell me if they are helpful. [Init Isolated Config](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#init-python-config) and [Init Python Config](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#init-isolated-conf)